# How to print a X with two letters inside a square

Tags: c++, algorithm, shapes, square

I am trying to make the this shape but stuck at here. I tried with counters more than one but failed again.

```
P p p p p p Q
p P p p p Q q
p p P p Q q q
p p p Q q q q
p p Q q Q q q
p Q q q q Q q
Q q q q q q Q
```

```
int main()
{  
    int loopLimit = 7;
    int upperCharacter = 0;
    
    do {
        int loopCounter = 0;

        do {
            if (loopCounter == upperCharacter) std::cout << "P ";
            else std::cout << "p ";
            loopCounter = loopCounter + 1;
        } while (loopCounter < loopLimit);

        upperCharacter = upperCharacter + 1;
        loopLimit = loopLimit - 1;
        std::cout << "\n";
    } while (loopLimit > 0);
}
```

My code currently outputs:

```
P p p p p p p 
p P p p p p 
p p P p p 
p p p P 
p p p 
p p 
p
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? (Even possible with pen and paper). What were your findings?

Comment: I recommend to use `for` loops with a fixed number of 7 cycles and think about which character positions should be upper-case row-by-row

Comment: I propose to try the following, in order to avoid that you program yourself into a corner. Use two nested loops (I'd prefer `for` but if you are more confident with `do while` stay with that) to output a square of all the same letters. Do not change those loops afterwards. Then use an `if-else` to select between two letters. Then use an `if-elseif-else` to select between three. Then four. I believe the trick you are supposed to learn here is making conditions. Complex structures of interdependent loops is an alternative, but my guess is that it would make things harder for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pen and a paper solved this question.

Here's the solution:

```
for (int satirSayaci = 1; satirSayaci < 8; satirSayaci++) {
        for (int karakterSayaci = 1; karakterSayaci < 8; karakterSayaci++)
        {
            if (karakterSayaci >= 8 - satirSayaci) {
                if (karakterSayaci == 8 - satirSayaci || karakterSayaci == satirSayaci) std::cout << "X ";
                else std::cout << "x ";
            } else {
                if (karakterSayaci == satirSayaci) std::cout << "P ";
                else std::cout << "p ";
            }
        }

        // Yeni bir satir yazdir
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) in mind,
I propose to try the following, in order to avoid that you program yourself into a corner.

Use two nested loops (I'd prefer `for` but if you are more confident with `do while` stay with that) to output a square of all the same letters. Do not change those loops afterwards.

Then use an `if-else` to select between two letters.
Then use an `if-elseif-else` to select between three.
Then four.

I believe the trick you are supposed to learn here is making conditions. Complex structures of interdependent loops is an alternative, but my guess is that it would make things harder for you.

I think a suitable sequence of letters to get right here would be:

- p
- Q on full first diagonal
- q
- P on full other diagonal, but check first diagonal afterwards
- Q on the other half of the second diagonal

Note that getting the order of the conditions right is important, e.g. for the point of diagonal crossing.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I solved this without three or more loops.

Comment: You can create your own answer with the final solution. And then decided which one you want to accept. "without three or more loops", i.e. two, would be exactly my propsoal. Nice to know that it helped.